# Can I do `type 'a entry = string * 'a * 'a entry;;` in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

It seems I can't.

I wanna understand why I can't.

It is sure that I can do `type 'a entry = Empty | Value of string * 'a * 'a entry;;`, so if I want to recursively define a type, I only can go the `union` route?

Comment: option `-rectypes` at the command line to enable recursive types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is confusing because it only mentions the type you *don't* want to use! However, I see from your title that you want to use a directly recursive type.

If you want directly recursive types, you need to turn on `-rectypes` on the command line. This is not something you really want to do most of the time, however. It allows too many types that *really* aren't what you want.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# type 'a entry = string * 'a * 'a entry;;
Error: The type abbreviation entry is cyclic
# ^D
$ ocaml -rectypes
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# type 'a entry = string * 'a * 'a entry;;
type 'a entry = string * 'a * 'a entry
#
```

The reason `-rectypes` isn't enabled by default is that it allows types to be given to many expressions that are actually coding errors. On balance, the extra flexibility isn't worth giving up the extra error detection.

Here's an example I found in an old OCaml mailing list message:

```
$ ocaml -rectypes
        OCaml version 4.00.0

# let f x = x :: x;;
val f : ('a list as 'a) -> 'a list = <fun>
#
```

With `-rectypes` turned on, this fairly absurd function is accepted. But really it only works on rather strange list types. Most likely the programmer meant to *append* the list to itself using `@` rather than `::`. Unfortunately this error won't be detected until much later when `-rectypes` is on.

As a side comment, and as newacct points out, you would probably soon find that the type in the title isn't so useful. It really can only represent cyclic or infinite structures. This is another reason that working without `-rectypes` isn't too difficult.

Comment: Actually, this type only works with cyclic structures. The type of streams (infinite lists) would be `type 'a entry = string * 'a * (unit -> 'a entry)`

Comment: True for a strict language like OCaml, but I was thinking a little more generally (sort of).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `type something = another type`, you are doing a *type synonym*, like a `typedef` in C. It makes an alias that you can use as a shortcut to refer to another type. It does not define a new type by itself. Hence, it cannot be recursive.

When you do `type something = SomeContructor of ...`, that defines a new algebraic data type. This can be recursive.

(Haskell and SML are more clear about this; they use `type` for type synonyms and `data` (Haskell)/`datatype`(SML) to define new algebraic data types.)

An algebraic data type does not necessarily need to have more than one alternative. It is syntactically valid to do

```
type 'a entry = Value of string * 'a * 'a entry
```

However, in this case, this is probably not useful, because, how could it end?